# javascript replace &lt; with < produces $lt;?

Tags: javascript, replace, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to use the javascript replace function to turn the html entity < into a <, like so

```
text = text.replace(/&lt;/g, "<");
text = text.replace(/&gt;/g, ">");
```

the initial text looks something like this:

```
&lt;img /&gt;
```

I am trying to get it to look like this:

```
<img />
```

However, when I run the above code, I get... this:

```
$lt;img />
```

Interestingly enough, the replacement of the > sign works fine, but the replacement of the < sign produces something totally unexpected (where the heck did that $ sign come from???).

I should also point out that if I add a space before the < in the replace function, like this:

```
text = text.replace(/&lt;/g, "< ");
```

It produces this:

```
< img />
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't get parsed into HTML like I want it to...

EDIT: If it helps, the text I am performing this on is the responseText of an XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: You get a dollar sign? Or is that a typo?

Comment: `replace` leaves the original string unchanged!

Comment: *"the initial text looks something like this: `&lt;img /&gt;` However, when I run the above code, I get... this: `$lt;img />`"* No, I really don't think you do. You've confused something in the process of shortening this for the question. Starting with `&lt;img /&gt;`, the replacements you've shown will definitely not give you `$lt;img />`.

Comment: @putvande yes I do indeed get a dollar sign there.

Comment: @BlackSheep sorry, I was in a hurry when I typed this out and left out the variable assignments. They do get assigned in the actual code I am running. And yes, it does indeed give me that $lt;

Answer (score 5):

You are overriding the replace when you do it like that.
Try to do it like a chain:

```
var text = '&lt;img /&gt;';
text = text.replace(/&lt;/g, "<").replace(/&gt;/g, ">");
// Output = <img />
```

Or you could do assign the replace to the `text` variable:

```
var text = '&lt;img /&gt;';
text = text.replace(/&lt;/g, "<");
text = text.replace(/&gt;/g, ">");
// Output = <img />
```

Comment: Again, I forgot to specify the assignments when I typed this out originally, the assignments are there in the actual code. The problem is that running the replace function as specified produces "$lt;" (and yes it is a dollar sign).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is rather embarrassing but it turns out that the reason that $ was appearing is because that was what was in the source code...

I replaced the $ with a & and now it works fine.

Thanks anyway for the feedback, and sorry to waste your time over a simple mistake like this.